# Quickest C# Serializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I need to serialize an OrderedDictionary, and I need it fast. I don't care about security or human-readability, I just need the fastest way to write the OrderedDictionary to file and read it back in again, so long as the serialization is consistent (same set of key-value pairs, same file contents). Is BinaryFormatter the best choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BinaryFormatter is almost certainly the fastest of the built-in serializers, but it wouldn't be very hard to measure the alternatives and check.

Comment: You should definitely look at the performance link in the other answer too - though not *instead* of doing your own tests.

Answer (score 5):

You might look into [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), Google's serialization format. There are several implementations for C#:

- [protosharp](http://code.google.com/p/protosharp/)
- [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)
- [protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)

There is a [performance comparison](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) online.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the fastest way, extra coding not being a problem, you could try this:

Serialize:
1. Write your dictionary data to an in-memory byte array. Assuming your dictionary isn't too huge, this should be relatively cheap, time-wise.
2. Write a small header containing the #records, and then write the array to file.

Deserialize:
1. Read the # items and instantiate your OrderedDictionary with that as the capacity.
2. Read the data back into an array, instantiate each object, and write back to the OrderedDictionary.

I think this won't be hugely faster than more traditional methods, but maybe worth a try if you're trying to eek out every last bit of performance.

A faster way would be to write your own IOrderedDictionary with intimate knowledge of your objects, and have it store them in a way optimized for fast serialization (e.g. a flat buffer that can be slammed to disk quickly). Perhaps even faster would be to use some indexing file format (maybe SQLite?) and write a caching IOrderedDictionary adapter to it. This would let you amortize the deserialization cost.